# Mininum cluster size in QGIS ST-DBSCAN sometimes not applied correctly

Tags: qgis, clustering, parameters, debugging

I have 7 point vector layers which I am clustering as a batch in QGIS using the standard ST-DBSCAN tool.

On one instance, I formed two groups based on different minimum cluster sizes: **7** or **10**. The other two parameters remained the same: maximum distance is 40m on a UTM Zone 32N projection; maximum time duration between points is 8h (28800000 ms).

2 of the 7 layers yield empty outputs for a minimum cluster size of 10 but form clusters for a minimum of 7. I analysed both of these clusters and noticed that, for one layer, there is **1** cluster of size 10 in the output for the latter. This cluster was not included as an output for the more rigid filter. I would assume its result would be this single group of points.

Minimum size in ST-DBSCAN does include the specified number, as I checked the other layers and saw cluster sizes of 10 in the output for this minimum size.

I ran the algorithm twice on a minimum of 10, yet the output is still empty.

On another instance, the parameter for maximum distance remained 40m. I reduced the maximum time duration between points to **4h** (14400000 ms) and again formed groups of minimum cluster sizes 7 and 10. I then compared the outputs to those of maximum time duration = 8h.

For **5** layers (one was the same that experienced the problem described earlier, the other belongs to the group with a minimum size of 10), clusters were filtered out that were temporally less than 4h apart. Three of them yielded blank outputs due to this.

Below is an example of a dataset clustered with max. distance 40m, max. time 8h, min. size 10 which yielded a blank output with a max. time of 4h:

```
datetime_lcl            CLUSTER_ID  CLUSTER_SIZE
2018-05-20 09:00:26.000     1           10
2018-05-20 13:30:31.000     1           10
2018-05-20 14:00:20.000     1           10
2018-05-20 14:30:24.000     1           10
2018-05-20 15:00:20.000     1           10
2018-05-20 15:30:21.000     1           10
2018-05-20 16:00:32.000     1           10
2018-05-20 16:30:21.000     1           10
2018-05-20 17:00:22.000     1           10
2018-05-20 17:30:23.000     1           10

2018-05-22 06:30:28.000     2           10
2018-05-22 07:00:21.000     2           10
2018-05-22 07:30:23.000     2           10
2018-05-22 08:30:29.000     2           10
2018-05-22 09:30:24.000     2           10
2018-05-22 10:00:27.000     2           10
2018-05-22 12:30:23.000     2           10
2018-05-22 13:00:29.000     2           10
2018-05-22 13:30:29.000     2           10
2018-05-22 14:00:26.000     2           10
```

Is this a known bug? What could be the reason for this behaviour?